# vb.net Connect to WIFI Network

Tags: vb.net

I have trying to figure out how to connect to a WIFI network through vb.net however I am having issues. I was walking through the link below however I am stuck on connection. I thought that my Connect routine would try to connect however it doesnt do anything meaning that it passes the  WlanConnect(ClientHandle, pInterfaceGuid, wlanConnectionParameters, IntPtr.Zero) however doesn't try to connect. After it executes the statement it returns to the button click. Shouldn't this line of code then try and connect to that network?

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi/WlanConnect.html

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("wlanapi.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function WlanConnect( _
    <[In]()> ByVal hClientHandle As IntPtr, _
    <[In]()> ByVal pInterfaceGuid As IntPtr, _
    <[In]()> ByVal pConnectionParameters As IntPtr, _
    <[In]()> ByRef pReserved As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function
''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''--------------------------------Native WiFi Structures----------------------------
''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS
    Public wlanConnectionMode As WLAN_CONNECTION_MODE
    Public strProfile As String
    Public pDot11Ssid As IntPtr
    Public pDesiredBssidList As IntPtr
    Public dot11BssType As DOT11_BSS_TYPE
    Public dwFlags As Int32
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure DOT11_BSSID_LIST
    Public Header As NDIS_OBJECT_HEADER
    Public uNumOfEntries As UInt32
    Public uTotalNumOfEntries As UInt32
    Public BSSIDs As IntPtr
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst:=6)> Public ucDot11MacAddress() As SByte
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure NDIS_OBJECT_HEADER
    Public Type As SByte
    Public Revision As SByte
    Public Size As SByte
End Structure
Public Enum WLAN_CONNECTION_MODE
    wlan_connection_mode_profile
    wlan_connection_mode_temporary_profile
    wlan_connection_mode_discovery_secure
    wlan_connection_mode_discovery_unsecure
    wlan_connection_mode_auto
    wlan_connection_mode_invalid
End Enum
Public Enum DOT11_BSS_TYPE
    dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure
    dot11_BSS_type_independent
    dot11_BSS_type_any
End Enum

Function HasConnectivity() As Boolean
    Dim hostInfo As System.Net.IPHostEntry
    Try 'to look for the logon server
        Dim sServer As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("logonserver")
        hostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(sServer.Remove(0, 2))
        Return True
    Catch 'theres no network connection
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Connect()
End Sub

Declare Function WlanConnect Lib "wlanapi.dll" (ByVal hClientHandle As IntPtr, _
                     ByRef pInterfaceGuid As Guid, _
                     ByRef pConnectionParameters As WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS, _
                     ByVal pReserved As IntPtr) As UInteger



Public Shared Sub Connect()
    Dim clienthandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim pInterfaceGuid As Guid
    Dim wlanConnectionParameters As New WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS
    wlanConnectionParameters.dot11BssType = DOT11_BSS_TYPE.dot11_BSS_type_any
    wlanConnectionParameters.dwFlags = 0
    wlanConnectionParameters.strProfile = "NetGear"
    wlanConnectionParameters.wlanConnectionMode = WLAN_CONNECTION_MODE.wlan_connection_mode_profile
    WlanConnect(ClientHandle, pInterfaceGuid, wlanConnectionParameters, IntPtr.Zero)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you are going to give me a thumbs down explain why. I was pretty detailed in my question and it is pretty straight forward. How do you connect to a WIFI network.

Comment: didn't downvote, but you should know that this isn't a debugging service. "doesn't do anything" isn't particularly useful, especially when you don't seem to have any error handling or explain what you've done to try and debug this yourself.

Comment: From my research I think that my code within Connect Sub would attempt to connect however it passes and doesn't do anything. I am not asking for a debug service, however I have searched and tried to debug the above code and am getting no where. Does any one have any idea's on how to connect to WIFI through vb.net.

Comment: you aren't checking return values. you aren't try/catching or whatever VB's equivalent is. Therefore the code's basically assuming that nothing could ever fail.

Comment: I will try that out. I didn't catch that. lol

Comment: Please post your trials and errors in a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the WLAN profile saved in your PC, this approach is simple.

```
Sub connectTo(ByVal name As String)
    Dim p = "netsh.exe"
    Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(p, "wlan connect " & name)
    sInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    sInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Process.Start(sInfo)
End Sub

'use the sub to connect to your AP. connectTo("myAP")
```

Otherwise, it is easier to use [ManagedWifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) or [SimpleWifi](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi) dll libraries. Here is my [code](https://github.com/lahiiru/QuotaClientApps/blob/master/QuotaWin/QuotaService/QuotaService.vb#L427) where I used SimpleWifi.dll to connect to a network with a passkey.